# Trying to download and install either SQL Server 2012 Express or SQL Server 2012

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have been trying to download and install either SQL Server 2012 Express or SQL Server 2012 Management Studio so I can access my remote SQL Server 2012 tables in my Dot Net Nuke website. I am using Windows 7 OS, X86. I have installed and verified that ALL of the following versions of the Dot Net Framework are installed and verified:

- .NET Framework 2.0
- .NET Framework 3.5
- .NET Framework 4.0
- .NET Framework 4.5
- .NET Framework 4.5.1
- .NET Framework 4.5.2

Each and every time I attempt to install either SQL Server 2012 Express or SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, I get an error message that

> You must install either .NET Framework 2.0 or .NET Framework 4.0 to install SQL Server Express 2012

I have done this many times, I have installed and uninstalled all of these, trying different orders and different sequences starting with 2.0 by itself, then adding the others. Same error. I have looked online and I can see that many others have had similar problems, sometimes a registry hack was suggested. However, I was wondering if anyone had a suggestion that works.

Answer (score 0):

Believe you need to install .net 3.5.1. as a feature first.
As the .net framework totally changed from 3 to 4.
And its the features inside 3.5.1 its actually looking for.
Mis-leading message I know.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did install .net 3.5.1 along with the others I mentioned. Perhaps the installations must be in a particular order.